# Can not set jquery ui dialog overlay background color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to set the Jquery UI dialog overlay background to different color. The following CSS is not working.

```
.ui-widget-overlay{background:red;}
```

Please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qchxcwr/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `modal` option to the dialogue settings then your fiddle will work.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  width: 300,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  modal: true
});
```

FYI I found this out by using the F12 feature in Chrome and looking for the overlay element which was not present. That led me to the JQuery UI [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).